# MongoDB Shell - access collection with period in name?

Tags: mongodb

I have found a collection in one of our MongoDB databases with the name `my.collection`.

Is there a way to access this collection from the MongoDB shell, despite it having a point in the name?

```
> db.my.collection.findOne();
null
```

I'm pretty sure that that is not correct.

Comment: It works for map/reduce collection which have a dot in their name, e.g. `tmp.mr.mapreduce_1294927200_2363`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct. If it returns null it means that the collection is empty.

Comment: With a similar problem I found mongo shell giving the Error "SyntaxError: unexpected token ILLEGAL" ... I found Laura's answer below is the way to access a collection with a period in the name.

Answer (score 106):

try this instead:

```
db["my.collection"].findOne();
```

you run into the same issue with hyphens or any other name that does not match on
[a-zA-Z_$][0-9a-zA-Z_$]

This limitation comes from valid named for javascript object properties.

Comment: I believe this should be the accepted answer because it explains the syntax and gives a useful workaround.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to drop 'Model\Tag_keys' collection. It is not working with this method `db['Model\Tag_keys'].drop()`

Comment: For db names that do not respect js object properties name rules, there is another solution below, based on `db.getCollection('_name')`

Answer (score 13):

if collection name is "my.collection"

> db.my.collection.findOne(); // OK
>   null

if collection name is "my.1.collection"

> db.my.1.collection.findOne(); // Not OK
>   SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

Fix:

> db["my.1.collection"].findOne(); // Now is OK
>   null

Answer (score 12):

Another foolproof method is:

```
db.getCollection("_SCHEMA").find()
```

While in the case of a underscore in the name, still cause a error with @Laura answer:

```
> db["_SCHEMA"].find()
2016-07-18T17:44:16.948+0200 E QUERY    [thread1] TypeError: db._SCHEMA is undefined :
@(shell):1:1
```

Comment: This should be the answer. Nothing else worked for a collection named "1" in the shell.