# how to resolve MongoDB error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL"?

Tags: mongodb

I am getting an error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

when I am trying to execute the command in mongoDB

```
db.17feb.find()
```

I read a [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719859/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-illegal) saying that names cannot start with numbers, but now as collection is already created and data exists in it, how can i retrieve using command? I am getting data when i am retrieving the data through java code

Can any1 help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can call object attributes with dot notation and square brackets. So try that:

```
db['17feb'].find();
```

**edit**

May that is a dube to that answer: 
[MongoDB Shell - access collection with period in name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680873/mongodb-shell-access-collection-with-period-in-name)